# Best way to programmatically detect if RubyGems.org is down?

Tags: rubygems

As part of our infrastructure monitoring we want to check if RubyGems.org is down.

The status.rubygems.org page is useful for humans, but is there a good way to programmatically check if RubyGems.org is down, e.g. an API call?

I didn't see a dedicated API call for getting the status in the API docs.

Answer (score 0):

Make a http request (follow redirects), if final response code is not 200, (404, 503, ...) the page is down

Comment: I'm not asking if only the web-site is down, but if any of the underlying services, like API or CDN is impacted.

Comment: @Tilo I think the OP means to make an HTTP request to an API endpoint (not to web site.) However it would be nice to have an API equivalent of status.rubygems.org so your monitor can tell if it is down for everyone or just you. (Is that important to you?)